# 100% Height on CSS Borders

Tags: css, height, border

I have been playing with the following code for a few hours now and just have not been able to get the yellow column borders within my container to extend to 100% height of the container.

I usually shorten my code before posting here but due to the left and right image panes being a factor I kept everything the way it was.

My jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/anvio/KErVs/2/

Anyone have any ideas on what I should try? Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us more context? 100% of module-container, body, table? I assume you are speaking of the vertical yellow lines. A picture with some markup is worth a thousand words =)

Comment: yea haha I am speaking about the yellow vertical lines

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you want:

If you add a `height` to `module-inner-container`

```
<div class="module-inner-container" style="height:38px;">
```

and you remove the `min-height` from `.module-container .body .content`

```
.module-container .body .content{
    min-height:100px;   //REMOVE THIS
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background:url("//image") repeat;
    position:relative;
}
```

The borders stretch to the bottom.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/KErVs/4/

Comment: That works however if you add or remove text within the cells such as the "Column 3 Test" the borders end up not stretching all the way down. The container is not going to be static so the borders need to be able to extend with the container.